# How to know if data sent from the wear are received on the phone

Tags: android, android-service, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I'm currently sending data from my wearable app with a "SendFileService". In this service I use the DataApi https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/DataApi
to send the data that are stored in a .csv file.
On the other hand, I have on my mobile app a "ListenerService" that receives the data and write them back in a .csv file on the mobile phone.

**Now my problem is that I would like to make sure that the data are received on the mobile phone before deleting the .csv file.** Do I need to implement a "SendService" and "ListenerService" on the other way to send a message from the mobile app to the wearable saying "ok data were received" ? I don't feel like it's the best strategy to use here...

By the way, I'm already making sure that the phone and the wearable are connected, using the NodeApi.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

For receive messages events, try using the `onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent)` method of [WearableListenerService](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService). This is actually used to receive events from other nodes, such as data changes, messages or connectivity events.

See also [Sending and Syncing Data](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html) for more information.